# How to attach build log files to Jenkins?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins, devops, jenkins-groovy

I'm building Jenkins pipeline and after pipeline fails with server installation some logs are generated on machine where server is being installed.

I want to attach those logs to Jenkins build so person can see that file from Jenkins build only instead of going to machine and find it out.

I saw a plugin [Copy To Slave Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Copy+To+Slave+Plugin) but for installation when I searched for it in Jenkins, it's not listed.

Could you please suggest which plugin will help me to attach log files to Jenkins build?

Comment: You want to attach logs in mail?

Comment: @codeLover, not to email but to build itself. So on build page, one can see log file and can download and check details.

Comment: Jenkins uses java.util.logging for the logging. User can view the logs on Web UI of Jenkins or on the server itself.

Please refer below link which provide information about the loggings in jenkins.

https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Logging

Comment: @RajPaliwal, thanks for pointing to it, but what i need is to upload server logs(i.e application server - server on which application build is being installed). The plugin you suggested is for Jenkins logs which is not my requirement.

Comment: #1 If you are talking about pipelines, I think you need the build and deploy log. Not the runtime log of your app. Is it right?  #2 What kinfy of technology are you  building or deploying with Jenkins? #3 Is you Jenkins able to execute ssh commands in the remote server where are your apps?

Answer (score 1):

Due to the complex nature of filesystems, Jenkins is not capable to copy logs from extraneous locations like those outside of the Jenkins root directory. This is for security reasons, which is why the **Copy to Slave Plugin** you referred to earlier has been discontinued.

In short, Jenkins spawns processes that spawn other processes that are owned by different users in the filesystem (e.g. root). For this reason, it is highly probable that the log files you are referring to are located elsewhere on the file system (i.e. not in $JENKINS_HOME), and thus are not owned by the **jenkins** user.

It is possible to use `cat` or `tail` on the log files in the Jenkins build itself. In combination with a plugin like [Log Parser](https://plugins.jenkins.io/log-parser), this can provide some nice output in another screen.

Answer (score 0):

I would be interested about what do you mean by “install”? Can the install happen during the building of a Docker image? Or in a pre-built Docker container? If this is the case, you can copy the “installed” files to the destination.

This would help you, because any log files created during the “install” can be copied out from the docker container and attached to the Jenkins build as an archived artifact.

For this, you don’t even need a plug-in.